# Need help understanding proving a multivariable limit exists

Tags: calculus, limits

I understood the reasoning up until equality 3. I cant understand it. Can anyone guide me through the reasoning to get to that inequality?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider 
$$3|y|\times\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$$
Then since you know that 
$$\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\leq 1$$
Then this will imply that the factor, lets say $\alpha = \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$ will 'scale down' the entire expression. This is what gives;$$3|y|\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\leq 3|y|$$.
Note that $\sqrt{y^2}=|y|$ since $y$ will always remain positive under the square root sign and the square will cancel. That's what gives it the equality. Finally, you want to somehow include $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ into the expression. And by simply adding this under the square root sign, you get the final equality that;
$$3\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<3\delta$$

Comment: OK it’s making more sense, now for the final step of the proof why did we choose delta to be (epsilon)/3 ? Im also having trouble understanding how the final inequality gives proof that the limit is 0.

Comment: Well you want the expression to be less than epsilon. So by letting $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ the 3 will cancel and you’re left with the correct equality. Since you got the equality to hold then that means the limit is in fact true. The first step of this question is to find the limit, then prove using $\epsilon - \delta$. That’s why you have the f(x,y) - 0 in the absolute value sign on line 1